# How to split a string by multiple separators - and know which separator matched

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, string-parsing, split

With `String.split` it is easy to split a string by multiple separators. You just needs to define a regular expression which matches all separators you want to use. For example

```
"1.22-3".split("[.-]")
```

results in the list with the elements `"1"`, `"22"`, and `"3"`. So far so good.

Now however I also need to know which one of the separators was found between the segments. Is there a straightforward way to achieve this?

I looked at `String.split`, its deprecated predecessor `StringTokenizer`, and other supposedly more modern libraries (e.g. [`StrTokenizer` from Apatche Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/text/StrTokenizer.html)), but with none of them I can get hold of the matched separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s quite simple if you retrace what `String.split(regex)` does and record the information which `String.split` ignores:

```
String source = "1.22-3";
Matcher m=Pattern.compile("[.-]").matcher(source);
ArrayList<String> elements=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> separators=new ArrayList<>();
int pos;
for(pos=0; m.find(); pos=m.end()) {
    elements.add(source.substring(pos, m.start()));
    separators.add(m.group());
}
elements.add(source.substring(pos));
```

At the end of this code, `separators.get(x)` yields to the separator between `elements.get(x)` and `elements.get(x+1)`. It should be clear that `separators` is one item smaller than `elements`.

If you want to have elements and separators in one list, just change the code to let these two lists be the same list. The items are already added in order of occurrence.

Comment: Nice! Just a little remark: `elements` in this code is slightly different to the result of `String.split` in that it may have an empty string element at the end. The code doesn't ignore trailing separators. But IMHO this is good.

Comment: It would be easy to fix that, however for most applications keeping the invariant that there are exactly `x` separators for `x+1` elements is more useful. That would be different if you collect both into one list, then allowing the list to end with a separator is fine. Looks like the requirement of keeping the separators implicitely forbids ignoring trailing separators, otherwise the results would be inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was looking at the wrong algorithm for what I was trying to achieve. Instead of using methods to split by separators, the following two-step approach was more successful:

- First, I implemented a [lexer (aka tokenizer, scanner)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) that splits the string into tokens which include the separators. I.e. split `1.22-3` into `1`, `.`, `22`, `-`, `3`
- Then, I implement a parser which interprets this token stream, i.e. distinguishes segments and their separators.

---

Possible implementation of the lexer:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public final class FixedStringTokenScanner {

    /**
     * Splits the given input into tokens. Each token is either one of the given constant string
     * tokens or a string consisting of the other characters between the constant tokens.
     *
     * @param input
     *            The string to split.
     * @param fixedStringTokens
     *            A list of strings to be recognized as separate tokens.
     * @return A list of strings, which when concatenated would result in the input string.
     *         Occurrences of the fixed string tokens in the input string are returned as separate
     *         list entries. These entries are reference-equal to the respective fixedStringTokens
     *         entry. Characters which did not match any of the fixed string tokens are concatenated
     *         and returned as list entries at the respective positions in the list. The list does
     *         not contain empty or <code>null</code> entries.
     */
    public static List<String> splitToFixedStringTokensAndOtherTokens(final String input, final String... fixedStringTokens) {
        return new FixedStringTokenScannerRun(input, fixedStringTokens).splitToFixedStringAndOtherTokens();
    }

    private static class FixedStringTokenScannerRun {

        private final String input;
        private final String[] fixedStringTokens;

        private int scanIx = 0;
        StringBuilder otherContent = new StringBuilder();
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        public FixedStringTokenScannerRun(final String input, final String[] fixedStringTokens) {
            this.input = input;
            this.fixedStringTokens = fixedStringTokens;
        }

        List<String> splitToFixedStringAndOtherTokens() {
            while (scanIx < input.length()) {
                scanIx += matchFixedStringOrAppendToOther();
            }
            storeOtherTokenIfNotEmpty();
            return result;
        }

        /**
         * @return the number of matched characters.
         */
        private int matchFixedStringOrAppendToOther() {
            for (String fixedString : fixedStringTokens) {
                if (input.regionMatches(scanIx, fixedString, 0, fixedString.length())) {
                    storeOtherTokenIfNotEmpty();
                    result.add(fixedString); // add string instance so that identity comparison works
                    return fixedString.length();
                }
            }
            appendCharacterToOther();
            return 1;
        }

        private void appendCharacterToOther() {
            otherContent.append(input.substring(scanIx, scanIx + 1));
        }

        private void storeOtherTokenIfNotEmpty() {
            if (otherContent.length() > 0) {
                result.add(otherContent.toString());
                otherContent.setLength(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: an answer to your own question?????????????/that too as if its smomebody else??????

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: I spent quite a while on this problem, and only after having found a solution, I decided that it may be worth having the question here.

Comment: You could have written it in first person mode

Comment: @vks: If it makes you happy, I can rewrite so that it is clear that I asked the question. Although the community recommends my original approach: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137369/191131